# jquery: Error $("div#created").scrollintoview is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails-3

EDIT: new error: Error Jquery not defined  line: 208

Line 208 in this code: https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview/blob/master/jquery.scrollintoview.js

[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error because I got everything working right in a jsfiddle, but when I added the code to my rails app it wont work. When I click on the error to learn more the section `complete: function() {` is highlighted.

Clicking the link causes the hidden div to appear and the link to become 'active' (color: red), however, the window does not scroll to the bottom of the div, and when I click the link to toggle everything nothing happens (div doesn't close and link stays red).

Original jsfiddle where things work : http://jsfiddle.net/Gr7BP/

### application.js

```
$(function() {

    $("#created").hide();

    $('a.created-button').click(function() {

        $('#created').toggle(function() {
            $('a.created-button').toggleClass('active');
            $('#created').scrollintoview({
                duration: "slow",
                direction: "y", 
                complete: function() {
                        // highlight the element so user's focus gets where it needs to be
                }
            });
        });
    });
});

$(function() {

    $("#stuff").hide();

    $('a.stuff-button').click(function() {

        $('#stuff').toggle(function() {
            $('a.stuff-button').toggleClass('active');
            $('#stuff').scrollintoview({
                duration: "slow",
                direction: "y",
                complete: function() {
                        // highlight the element so user's focus gets where it needs to be
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

### footer

```
<footer>
 <div id="created-by"><a class="created-button">Created by</a></div> 
 <div id="cool-stuff"><a class="stuff-button">Cool stuff</a></div>

</footer>
<div id="created">

</div>
<div id="stuff">

</div>
```

### css

```
#created {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: green;

}
#stuff {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: white;

}

.active {
    color: red;
}
```

edit: [image: shows error with non camel casing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>It is because the function you are calling is `scrollIntoView()` (**in camelCasing**) while the function defined is `scrollintoview()` (**not in camelCasing**)</del>

<del>Note : JavaScript is a *case sensitive* language.</del>

Make sure you have included the JavaScript files in the correct order. First, load the `jQuery` library, then the `scrollintoview` plugin and finally your `application.js`

EDIT: Updated the answer as per the discussion in comments.

Comment: sorry but that doesn't do it, I changed it to camel casing as a last resort after googling around and found some people calling it that way, just forgot to change back when posting the question. Sorry about the mix up but its not the case and edited above to show.

Comment: Are you including the `scrollintoview` plugin before `application.js`?

Comment: I was pasting it at the top of my application.js but when I just included it separately above the other file I got a new js error which says "Jquery not defined" and points to line 208 https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview/blob/master/jquery.scrollintoview.js

Comment: In what order are you including your JavaScript files? Make sure that `jQuery` is included first followed by the plugin and finally `application.js`. I don't see anything else that might be creating this problem.

Comment: yep it was the ordering of these files, thanks for helping me through it, I never knew they needed to be in specific order.

Answer (score 0):

A callback function will probably do the trick.

```
 $('div#created').scrollintoview({
      duration: "slow",
      direction: "y"
 }, function() {
      // do something   
 });
```